# redirect in javascript click event using flask framework

Tags: javascript, python, redirect, flask, highcharts

I am using a Highcharts example I found to redirect user to a site once they click a bar on the chart that is rendering on the page. This is working fine using only java script, but I am using python flask framework and I want to redirect to a route such as /index or /about something like that. However this messes up when I give redirect in that manner. I have tried to use the url_for but that is not working for me either. Not sure what is the correct way to do this?

here is the jsFiddle I found : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click-url/

```
<script>
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
                        this.options.key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 29.9,
        name: 'USA',
        key: 'United_States'
    }, {
        y: 71.5,
        name: 'Canada',
        key: 'Canada'
    }, {
        y: 106.4,
        name: 'Mexico',
        key: 'Mexico'
    }]
}]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
window.location.replace('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
                        this.options.key)
```

Comment: Im probably messing this up. But Im giving as such with / being the route to my index page. and I have a key as about: window.location.replace('/' + this.options.key)  Some how when I get this is see the redirect going to /undefined as if key is not getting found.

Comment: Hmm it must have something to do with the highcharts, I'm not sure

Comment: Matt is your data format exactly the same as shown in your jsFiddle example?